# Is possible to combine swig generated datatypes and ctypes function

Tags: python, c, ctypes, swig

I am writing a python wrapper for a C library with ctypes and I have a C function that returns a structure. But that structure is defined in another C file and that file is wrapped by swig.

I simplified structure and code.

This structure is wrapped by swig.

```c
struct point {
  int x;
  int y;
};
```

This function is wrapped with ctypes.

```c
struct point add_points(struct point a, struct point b) {
  struct point c;
  c.x = a.x + b.x;
  c.y = a.y + b.y;
  return c;
}
```

Python wrapper.

```py
import swigModule # contains class point generated from c structure point
import ctypes

_libc = ctypes.CDLL('./c_file.so')

def add_points(a, b):
    add_points = _libc.add_points
    add_points.argtypes = [swigModule.point, swigModule.point,]
    add_points.restype = swigModule.point,
    result = add_points(a, b)
    return result
```

Problem is, I can't use swig generated class `point` as restype and argtype in ctypes. But I can't write my own structure wrapper like this.

```py
class Point(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", ctypes.c_int),
                ("y", ctypes.c_int)]
```

Because the fields of the C structure are hidden, I don't have access to the source code. I only know the name of the structure from swig wrapper.

I have two C files, one is generated with swig and has structure data types. And another has functions and is wrapped with ctypes. I want to use data class from swig in my ctypes functions.

How can I map swig class generated from c structure to ctypes class so that I can use it as a return type?

Comment: It's totally possible to do this sort of thing, see for instance my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41212424/168175 but it's almost always not a good idea to do so because the result will often be fragile

Comment: Fyi if this C function took structs by pointer instead of value and didn't create new instances this would be pretty trivial to solve. I think you could write code that guessed the layout using swig wrapped structs provided they always wrapped all the members and they were structs in the strictest C sense (i.e. no C++)

Comment: @Flexo I tried your solution and I don't think I can use it. 
Because I have files generated by swig and I only have access to .py file. Is it possible to use only the .py file that is generated by swig to map returned pointer to the structure to class?

Comment: You'll need the .so/.pyd to deduce the offset and size of the members of the struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's totally possible to make SWIG and ctypes work together, in various different ways, as I'll show with a few examples below. However with that said there is a big caveat: in my experience it's almost never going to get you something that's maintainable, portable, extensible, etc. so I've tended to favour alternatives options where possible. (Those probably include asking the original authors for the source using whatever means of persuasion is appropriate, re-writing the whole thing from scratch, or simply using an alternative library).

Anyway, let's assume you've got a SWIG wrapped library built for a given Python version.   And for whatever reason they didn't wrap your favourite function. So you'd like to just use ctypes to monkey patch something into the SWIG generated code. That can actually be pretty easy, provided:

1. The functions you want to call only take and return objects by pointer, not by value.
2. The functions you want to call only return existing instances of your types and don't malloc new ones. (There's a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41212424/168175) for that, but it starts to make stuff difficulty again, really fast).
3. The structs you care about actually wrapped all the members you cared about and (if it's C++ code) they're POD types.

Your case doesn't really match those constraints, but for a warm-up exercise let's take a look at doing this with the following "easy_mode" function because it does let us introduce one key point:

```
struct point *easy_mode(struct point *a, struct point *b) {
  a->x += b->x;
  a->y += b->y;
  return a;
}
```

This function is pretty easy to use given an existing SWIG wrapper that doesn't already wrap it, but does wrap the struct. We can simply use the SWIG code to create instances of the struct and the extract a pointer from them to give (via ctypes) to the exported but not wrapped function, for example:

```
from ctypes import *
from test import point

p1 = point()
p2 = point()
p1.x = 123
p1.y = 156
p2.x = 123
p2.y = 156

so = CDLL('./_test.so')

so.easy_mode(int(p1.this), int(p2.this))
print(p1.x)
print(p1.y)
```

Is sufficient to call this function and as we know the return type is really just modifying `p1` we can use that knowledge and roll with it. The key thing to take away from this though is that calling `int(p1.this)` gets you an integer representation of the pointer that the SWIG object is proxying for. And that's all ctypes needs for a pointer.

Let's take this forward though, to the case where we pass and return structs by value. This is much harder because the way the function gets called depends on the size and members of the struct. Their types and ordering matters. And it varies from architecture to architecture. It can even vary within a given architecture based on various things. Luckily ctypes (via libffi, which is an interesting thing in and of itself if you've never seen it before) hides all that from us.

So now our targeted missing function can be something like this:

```
struct point add_them(struct point a, struct point b) {
  struct point ret = { a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y };
  return ret;
}
```

The problem is that in the scenario of having just an existing SWIG module that doesn't call it we know absolutely nothing about the members of `struct point`. That's critical to being able to call by value. Sure we can make some guesses and if it's simple enough to just guess then you may as well do that and be done with it for ctypes.

Fortunately the existence of a useable SWIG wrapping of the struct gives us (if a few assumptions hold true) enough to make at least a good enough guess as to the types/layout of the struct. Furthermore since we know how to get a pointer to the underlying memory an instance of the struct uses we can construct tests that will show us things about the layout. If all goes well we can use that to construct a ctypes `Structure` definition of fields that will be compatible.

The crux of this is that we're going to `memset` an instance to 0 and then try to set each byte to a marker value one at a type, using the SWIG generated setter code for each member. When we inspect that we can make the deductions we need.

Before we can do that however it's helpful to have an upperbound on the size of the struct. We can get that by calling `malloc_useable_size()` which tells us what the heap allocation got rounded up to. So we can do something like this:

```
useable_size = CDLL(None).malloc_usable_size

upper_size_bound = useable_size(int(p1.this))
buffer_type = POINTER(c_char * upper_size_bound)
print('Upper size bound is %d' % upper_size_bound)

choose_type = dict([(1, c_uint8), (2, c_uint16), (4, c_uint32)]).get

def generate_members(obj):
  for member_name in (x for x in dir(obj) if not x[0] == '_' and x != 'this'):
    print('Looking at member: %s' % member_name)
    def pos(shift):
      test = point()
      memset(int(test.this), 0, upper_size_bound)
      pattern = 0xff << (8 * shift)
      try:
        setattr(test, member_name, pattern)
      except:
        return -1
      return bytes(cast(int(test.this), buffer_type).contents).find(b'\xff')
    a=[pos(x) for x in range(upper_size_bound)]
    offset = min((x for x in a if x >= 0))
    size = 1 + max(a) - offset
    print('%s is a %d byte type at offset %d' % (member_name, size, offset))
    pad = [('pad', c_ubyte * offset)] if (offset > 0) else []
    class Member(Structure):
        _pack_ = 1
        _fields_ = pad + [(member_name, choose_type(size))]

    yield Member
```

This takes every member that SWIG knows about for the given struct and, having computed an array working out the offset of each byte of a given field then computes both the offset and size of that member. (The use of min/max means it should work with both BE and LE hardware). We can take the size and map it onto a type. Given the knowledge we now have we could compute the layout that best matches what we learned. I cheated though and for each member generated a struct that has padding added at the beginning to position the member at exactly the offset we computed. The python code above is a generator that yields a ctypes `Structure` that has a member of the right size/type at the right offset.

In reality you'll need to deduce a lot more. Floating point numbers would probably be best served with known exactly representable values. We need to consider both signed and unsigned types. Arrays, strings and even nested types could be done. It's all possible on a trial+error basis but that's left as an exercise for the reader.

Finally we need to pull it together. Since I cheated with the one structure per member thing above all we need to do is merge these into a union:

```
class YourType(Union):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = list(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, generate_members()))
    _anonymous_ = string.ascii_lowercase[:len(_fields_)]
```

With that we've now got enough to work with to call our `add_them` function:

```
MyType=YourType

y=MyType()
y.x = 1 
y.y = 2

add_them = so.add_them
add_them.argtypes = [MyType, MyType]
add_them.restype = MyType

v=add_them(y,y)
print(v)
print('V: %d,%d' % (v.x, v.y))
```

Which does actually work to call a ctypes function using just information derived from a pre-existing SWIG module.

I'd still recommend not doing it in any real code though!

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting question for sure! It has been asked before, see [question 7886790](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886790/combining-ctypes-and-swig). 
That question does not have an accepted answer, though. Doing research on the internet turns up little useful information.

The general consensus seems to be "*use either `ctypes` **or** SWIG*".
So I'm afraid that the answer to your question is **no**. :-(

---

What I gathered from researching this question:

- SWIG is better when you have to interface to multiple languages.
- `ctypes` is better when you don't want to compile stuff.
- `ctypes` works well with C code, but only with C++ code that has `extern C` interfaces.
- `boost.Python` comes up a lot for interfacing C++ to Python.

You might find the answers to [question 135834](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135834/python-swig-vs-ctypes) informative.